# How to Observe any View Change on JS side from Android native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I want to be able to get some sort of indication for Android Java end for when the View has changed on the JS side for React Native. This can be from TabNavigation or StackNavigation change of View.

I had a look in the UIManagerModuleListener interface willDispatchViewUpdates but that doesn't seem to work.

So are there any sort of Hack or ways i can find out if the View has changed?